# Ubuntu 23.04 - Slack notification problem

Tags: gnome, unity, notification, 23.04

Slack notifications in Ubuntu 23.04, won't go away

[image]

I have tried using:

> settings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-icons-emblems false

But this seems to disable notifications for all applications.

I just want this to work properly meaning that want to see notifications and once i check them out to have them removed.

Comment: Same thing happens with Chrome notification counts. The feature is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will become clearer to you, as it became clearer to me ...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3g8Y.png)